# Economical Suborbital Trajectory Analysis Software

Tags: trajectory, software, sub-orbital, analysis

Got my two LR-101's, found some reasonably sized surplus LOX/RP-1 and pressurization tanks, found plans for fabricating valves, designed my vehicle, made an excel based back of the envelope sizing program. Now I need trajectory analysis software to see how high and fast this combination will fly. I looked at some free-ware offers most were dead-end links, codes for high end operating systems, out of business or bogus download sites. Down loaded Orbital and freaked out on the learn curve.

Is there any windows based trajectory analysis software out there other than soild fuel model rocket type that is reasonably priced (under $300 USD). Not a game just a basic program. Input basic vehicle parameters push the enter button and get graphic flight path results????

Comment: Have you tried with [2DZAP](http://www.ecf.utoronto.ca/~pavacic/2dzap/)?

Comment: http://www.princeton.edu/sgs/publications/sgs/archive/15_2_Forden.pdf ... http://www.codeforge.com/s/0/ballistic-missile-trajectory ... just ideas.